# how to get the error message from the Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

When I write testcase with Robot Framework, I write some error log with Robot Framework API `logger.error(msg, html=False)`, when the test is finished, how can I get the error message?

For example, after the test is finished, log is as below:
[image]

how can I get the error message that marked in red rect?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the error message"? Do you want a program that can read the output.xml and extract the error message?

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to get the error message in the listener, such as in the end_test method

Answer (score 1):

@Alex Bruce. I was having the same issue. Use "Run Keyword And Ignore Error" with variable infront of it. That variable will have the Fail result you are looking for.

```
> *** Settings *** Documentation     Test Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers Library           Selenium2Library    timeout=10
> 
> *** Variables *** ${BROWSER}        chrome ${SLEEP}          3
> 
> *** Test Cases *** Testing
>     Error Logging
> 
> *** Keywords *** Open Google
>     Open Browser    http://google.com/    ${BROWSER}
>     Wait Until Page Contains    Damn    timeout=1
> 
> Error Logging
>     ${ErrorChk} =    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Open Google
>     log    ${ErrorChk[1]}

Starting test: Error.Testing
20170731 17:57:13.874 :  INFO : Opening browser 'chrome' to base url 'http://google.com/'
20170731 17:57:19.131 :  INFO : </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="selenium-screenshot-1.png"><img src="selenium-screenshot-1.png" width="800px"></a>
20170731 17:57:19.132 :  FAIL : Text 'Damn' did not appear in 1 second
20170731 17:57:19.133 :  INFO : ${ErrorChk} = ('FAIL', u"Text 'Damn' did not appear in 1 second")
20170731 17:57:19.133 :  INFO : Text 'Damn' did not appear in 1 second
Ending test:   Error.Testing
```

Comment: @AlexBruce: Please use this test case as your reference.

Look at my main post plz.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks @ijaved

Answer (score 0):

Hi @AlexBruce Maybe you can use this KW:

```
Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='FAIL'    FAIL    msg=${message}
```

there you can chose the message in ${message}